# C# implement interface with properties that are interface.

Tags: c#

I am using EF code first to generate my db and I do need concrete property for ICollection of EF entity models. I am writing a data access layer ( Using generic classes) however hit the following road block with using interfaces in my generic class as shown below.

```
public interface ITestClassProp
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public class TestClassProp : ITestClassProp
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}


public interface ITestClass
{
    ICollection<ITestClassProp> TestProp { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    // works
    //public ICollection<ITestClassProp> TestProp { get; set; }
    // does not work
    public ICollection<TestClassProp> TestProp { get; set; }
}
```

Am I totally mis using the interfaces? why cant I use TestClassProp instead of ITestClassProp?

Thanks

Comment: Because you are redefining the interface. If you want to use concrete types, you have to define it in the interface.

Comment: Because the `ITestClass` interface has a property of type `ICollection<ITestClassProp>`. You aren't implementing the interface if your is a `ICollection<TestClassProp>`

Comment: You could make this a generic interface `ITestClass<T> where T : ITestClassProp`.  Then `TestClass : ITestClass<TestClassProp>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've currently written your code, you are not satisfying the requirement you've imposed via your `ITestClass` interface, which is to have a property of `ICollection<ITestProp>`.

One way around this is to actually make ITestClass generic, but provide a generic constraint of `ITestClassProp`

```
public interface ITestClassProp
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public class TestClassProp : ITestClassProp
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}


public interface ITestClass<T> where T : ITestClassProp
{
    ICollection<T> TestProp { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass : ITestClass<TestClassProp>
{
    public ICollection<TestClassProp> TestProp { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to provide any concrete type that implements `ITestProp` to your `ICollection`.

Comment: I end up solving with the generic class as you shown here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

When you implement an interface, you have to implement the methods/properties of that interface with the same signature. Since the interface declares `ICollection<ITestClassProp> TestProp { get; set; }` then your `TestClass` must also declare `ICollection<TestClassProp> TestProp { get; set; }`.

The reason this is necessary is that other classes that know about the interface but not the concrete class are expecting the property to be `ICollection<ITestClassProp>` and not `ICollection<TestClassProp>`.

Comment: Thanks Mason. I appreciate your answer. i have mark david L as answer as that is how I end up solving the problem and might be useful for others who are looking for quick solutions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the interface declares a property of type ICollection, but you implement it as ICollection, which has a totally different signature.

You might want to read up on [covariance and contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) also.